# Implementability of proof assistants for Infinitary logics with finite many terms

Tags: implementation, software-request, normalization, decidable

[Infinitary logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary) is a natural consequence of extending the length of proofs of first-order logic to a infinite ordinal level.

By definition, since proof lengths are infinitely long, one should not expect to implement a proof assistant that can check proofs on an Infinitary logic...

But what if one only needs to check proofs of finite terms in Infinitary logic?

Can we have decidable checkers to check the proofs in the following Infinitary logic:

- $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$, Countable infinite logical connectives and finite quantifiers which use only finitely many terms.

This is the simplest infinitary logic, enjoying the downward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem and the Barwise Compactness Theorem.

- $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$, Any ordinal number of logical connectives and finite quantifiers which use only finitely many terms.
- $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega_1}$, Countable infinite logical connectives and Countable infinite quantifiers which use only finitely many terms.

It is dangerous and powerful enough to define genuine wellorderings:

$$
\forall x_0 ...\forall x_n...(\neg(\bigwedge\limits_{n<\omega}x_{n+1}< x_n))
$$

Comment: I’m having trouble figuring out the question. Are you just asking if there is a (finite) decidable proof system for infinite logic?  This is just a proof/computability theoretic question, right?  You are not asking about mechanical proof assistants, correct?  Also the fact that you can use say ZFC or DTT to prove infinity statements also isn’t sufficient, since ZFC has a higher strength than $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1, \omega}$, yes?  If so, then I think MO would be a better place to ask this.  Maybe the question should be moved.

Comment: @JasonRute Why MO and not cstheory.stackexchange.com? And the question of being able to use countable logical connectives directly in the currently available proof assistants is something I think fits the topic of this sub-community.

Comment: Again, I’m not clear on the question being asked.  If it is just how do you reason in, say, Lean about an infinite conjunct, that is a fair question and easy to answer, but I thought you wanted a proof system for exactly the logic $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$.  Maybe I misunderstood.  cstheory.stackexchange.com would be fine too.  I just mentioned MO because I’m sure someone there knows the answer.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4010340/decidability-results-for-mathcall-omega-1-omega

Comment: And what do you mean by “finite term”.  Do you mean it in a formal sense?  If so, what language is this term written in?

Comment: @JasonRute I think the restriction compared to full Infinitary logics is that only finitely many variables are allowed, otherwise trying to write sentences with finite terms would be impossible. doi.org/10.1007/3-540-56039-4_36

Comment: @JasonRute There are quite a few requestability questions under the tag [software-request] about proof assistants for specific mathematical structures. I think this question still meets the subcommunity requirements.

Comment: @EmberEdison: there is no need to be so defensive. Jason kindly asked you to clarify your question. Let me try also. Are you (a) talking about implementing a proof assistant for infinitary logic, or (b) talking about how to formalize infinitary logic so that we can prove meta-theorems about it? To a large extent (a) is impossible because you stand no chance of having a decidable proof checker.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I think both of those questions have been addressed. On the one hand doi.org/10.1007/3-540-56039-4_36 tells us that there is a little bit of infinite logic that has computable content, and on the other hand the answer has now told us that most proofs of infinite logic are undecidable. And the proof assistant can handle infinite conjunctions. I guess I shouldn't expect proof assistants to be able to handle infinite quantifiers.

Comment: @EmberEdison infinite quantifiers like your well ordering example can be turned into valid Lean by quantifying over sequences.  If you like I edit my answer with an example.

Comment: @JasonRute I don't disagree that there exists a portion of infinite quantifier formulas that can be written in the proof assistant. But considering the broadest case, wouldn't it really be stuck on the universe levels? I'd appreciate it if you could write about infinite quantifiers in detail.

Comment: I already added something to the bottom.  Do you want me to mention universes?  (It really isn't an issue, but I see why you might think it is.)

Comment: @JasonRute I guess I have to admit that I don't get the relationship between universe levels and quantifiers... Why do quite a few quantisation operations raise the universe levels, while (some) infinite quantisation doesn't?

Comment: @EmberEdison I added an example with higher cardinalities of both quantifiers and conjunctions.  I still don't understand the question about universe levels.  I think it is best to ask it as a separate question on this site.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this question is well formed for the following reasons.  As stated in the answer to a [similar math stack exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4010340/decidability-results-for-mathcall-omega-1-omega), there are uncountable many $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1, \omega}$ sentences, so it wouldn't make sense to talk about a finite proof of a given sentence.  Not only would the proof not be checkable in finite time, but it wouldn't even be possible in general to express the statement you are trying to prove in finite time.

Now, one can certainly talk about a countable fragment of $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1, \omega}$.  (Note, just restricting the number of variables doesn't make the number of sentences countable.  For example, consider the infinite sentence $(1 > 0) \land (1 + 1 > 0) \land (1 + 1 + 1 > 0) \land \ldots$.  It encodes the sequence 1, 2, 3, ... and similarly, all sequences of natural numbers can be encoded into infinite sentences as such.).

In computability theory, one such countable fragment is the fragment of computable infinitary formulas.  This is well-studied.  I doubt this version has a nice finite proof theory though.  Consider the following example:
$$\bigwedge_n \text{$1=1$ if $\phi_{e}(0)$ doesn't halt in $n$ steps, else $1=0$}$$
This can be made into a valid computable $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1, \omega}$ sentence, but proving it is true for an arbitrary $e$ would be the same as a proof that the program $\phi_e(0)$ doesn't halt.  Now, note, if $\phi_e(0)$ doesn't halt, this formula is deducible with an infinite proof, and even a computable one at that, namely check that the $n$th term is $1=1$ and give a trivial proof of that.  So whatever you mean by "decidable checkers to check the proofs in the following Infinitary logic", you can't ask for a finite deduction method for this fragment of $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1, \omega}$ which can be used to prove any computable infinite statement that has an infinite proof, even a computable one.  Otherwise, you could solve the halting problem by searching for a finite proof of the corresponding infinite formula.

Maybe there is some nice proof-theoretic fragment of $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1, \omega}$ with a nice form of finite deduction.  I'm not an expert in this field.  But as my above example shows, it is not clear what "nice" means, and it isn't clear it is going to agree with the usual infinite deduction of $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1, \omega}$.

---

Since this is a proof assistant forum, let me mention that almost all common proof assistants can handle infinite conjunctions and can prove any reasonable statement in $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1, \omega}$.  An infinite conjunction is just a form of universal quantification.  Here is one of the above examples in Lean:

```
def f : Nat -> Nat
| 0 => 1
| n+1 => (f n) + 1

-- This expresses /\_n 1 + ... + 1 > 0 
theorem foo (n : Nat) : f n > 0 := by
  induction n with
  | zero =>
      rw [f]
      norm_num
  | succ n ih =>
    rw [f]
    calc
    f n + 1 ≥ f n := by norm_num
    _      > 0    := ih
```

Indeed, Lean can talk about every computable $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1, \omega}$ sentence (using the axiom of choice), but for the same argument above there are going to be sentences with infinite proofs (even computable ones) for which Lean has no (finite) proof.

*Update*: Further, handling infinite quantifiers is just as easy.  Instead of quantifying over a type `A` infinitely many times, you quantify over sequences $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$ of elements in `A` for some index set $I$.  This is equivalent to quantifying over the type `I -> A` of functions from `I` to `A`.  So your well-order example becomes:

```
theorem nat_wellordered : ∀ (x : Nat -> Nat), ¬ ∀ (n : Nat), x (n + 1) < x n := sorry
```

Similarly, you can show `Int` is not well ordered:

```
theorem int_not_wellordered : ∃ (x : Nat -> Int), ∀ (n : Nat), x (n + 1) < x n := sorry
```

One can even work with infinite conjunctions and infinite quantifiers much larger than countable.  In this example, we can express that any universe `Type u` doesn't have an increasing chain of cardinalities of size `Ordinal.{u+1}` (which is the ordinal corresponding to the size of the next higher universe `Type (u+1)`.  The details are particular to Lean, but you can do similar things in other theorem provers.

```
theorem bar : ∀ (X : Ordinal.{u+1} -> Type u), ¬ ∀ (α β : Ordinal.{u+1}),
  α < β -> Cardinal.mk (X α) < Cardinal.mk (X β) := sorry
```